# mongo dump and restore (when restoring in different os)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am working on a project, there I need to dump a database from windows and need to restore it on a centos server.

Whenever I do that, there is some error.

Like - error reading database: (Unauthorized) not authorized on mydatabase to execute command

or

error connecting to host: could not connect to server: connection() : auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.

Both os have the same mongo version that is 4.2

How can I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

The error `not authorized on mydatabase to execute command` indicates that either you have not authenticated, or the authenticated user has not been granted the appropriate permissions to execute that command.

`Authentication failed` means just that.  The server side log may have more detail, like the user and database names used in the auth attempt.

To fix these, make sure:

- you are providing authentication credentials
- the user account you are using has already been created in the server
- the user account has been granted permission for that command on the correct database/collection

The [Security](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/security/#security) page in the docs might be a good place to start.

Comment: Hey Joe,
Thanks for answering.
So, I did created username and password for the database with role as "dbOwner" and used that credentials for restoring on the server. The same error persists.
Can you tell me where to start looking at this?

Comment: mongorestore --username aditsinh --password pass /home/centos/skybridge/docker_backend/skybridge/database/

Comment: I tried
mongorestore -u aditsinh /home/centos/skybridge/docker_backend/skybridge/database/

This too

Comment: The log entry doesn't tell you what command was refused?  Also check the mongod log to make sure the authentication is using the database that you created the user in.

Comment: I am not sure, how to check log entry. :(

Comment: Just as a wild guess, you might try using the `--authenticationDatabase` and/or `--authenticationMechanism` command line options